# Getting wix toolset not installed error in azure devops upon building wixproj

Tags: azure-devops, wix, windows-installer, azure-pipelines

I am creating an MSI installer with Wix and wrote a task in the azure DevOps pipeline which builds the MSI solution file using MSBuild. When the code is pushed to remote the pipeline runs the task but my task returns the error saying WiX toolset is not installed hence the build fails. Though it is assured that the MSBuild task works as it is building other projects in the solution.

```
##[error]Process 'MSBuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
##[error][Path to wixproj](44,5): Error : The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/
```

Is there any way to install Wix toolset using pipeline?
Or any workaround which might help?

Please note that I am using a custom job pool if that might be a cause for this issue.

Comment: Have you install the Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools in the machine where the job pool exists?

Comment: Actually, we don't know if it was installed, most probably not else we won't be getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the issue is that your .wixproj is out of date and thus does not handle the breaking changes made in MSBuild 2017. You can re-create your .wixproj using the latest templates in Visual Studio or walk through the [steps laid out here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5804#issuecomment-532663590).

Essentially, you need to update the way that MSBuild imports the `wix.targets` because MSBuild 2017 changed the way they did that.

Comment: Hi Rob! I am currently using VS2022 with the latest extension, also have cross-checked that my file is using the latest template for the imports. My wixproj is building on my local machine but it doesn't when I push it to remote.